ASUS IPv6 DNS server configuration
I have configured my ASUS ZenWifi AX router to use my local DNS server for both LAN clients and as an upstream (WAN) DNS server:

LAN - DHCP Server: DNS Server 1: 192.168.78.42 / Advertise router's IP in addition to user-specified DNS: No
WAN - Internet Connection: WAN DNS Setting : Assign : Manual Setting : DNS Server: 192.168.78.42

These settings work as intended for IPv4, but the equivalent for IPv6 does not. These are my settings for IPv6:

LAN - DHCP Server: IPv6 DNS Server: 2a02:908:532:bca0:1e69:7aff:feaf:7455
IPv6: IPv6 DNS Setting: Connect to DNS Server automatically: No / IPv6 DNS Server 1: 2a02:908:532:bca0:1e69:7aff:feaf:7455 / IPv6 DNS Server 2: 2606:4700:4700::1111

The second DNS Server is Cloudflare, which is also used as forwarder in my Bind9 config on the local DNS server.
This configuration is very unreliable, frequently returning errors such as server can't find domain2.internal: NXDOMAIN before successfully resolving the domains a couple of seconds later.
When activating "IPv6 DNS Setting: Connect to DNS server automatically", lookups work much better, although I cannot configure custom IPv6 DNS servers on the IPv6 screen then.
In both cases, the router's IPv6 addresses (2a02:908:532:bca0:642:1aff:fe33:a5c0, 2a02:908:532:bca0:b37e:71d0:3747:e410) are propagated to the clients instead of the custom server addresses, but the router seems to use the DNS server configured on the "LAN – DHCP Server" screen itself.
So my question is:
What is the use case for deactivating automatic connection, and providing DNS server addresses?
In which context does it work, considering that it seems to interfere with IPv6 DNS lookups for me?
Is it possible to get the router to actually send my local DNS server address to the clients instead of its own address(es)?

For DNS, IPv4 DNS servers can by used for IPv6, and vice versa. You are not required to use a DNS server with an IPv6 address unless you only use IPv6. IPv4 DNS servers are perfectly capable of resolving AAAA records, and IPv6 DNS servers are perfectly capable of resolving A records. Using dual-stack means you do not need to set up separate IPv6 DNS servers.

Yes, I am aware of that, but I wanted to configure an IPv6-only environment (which might not be possible with the current Asus firmware, at least via the web interface). I have not yet tried to manipulate the router configuration via command line.

I think you might be searching too deep about the why/where of this feature – it's much more likely that the DNS cache software in the ASUS is simply broken when it comes to IPv6...

You're probably right, I am overly curious.
